# How to prevent Epoxy from sagging/dripping

Tags: concrete, anchor, epoxy

I have to anchor a bolt to concrete, but I can only find 2 component epoxy in "medium viscosity" around here (Brazil). I made a test setup to see how much might drip out and it is much more than i would like. What is the best wait to prevent that?

Its open time is 50 minutes, I took this picture 1 hour after I made the test.

[image: epoxy drip test]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microballoons. Tiny glass or phenolic bubbles. They are the standard product for mixing into epoxy when you need a paste. Should be available at any place that caters to boat repair.

Plugging the hole with masking tape or similar may also work perfectly well in this case. If you can arrange to hold the bolt in with pressure, you could also use a large washer and a nut to hold a rubber or felt washer/gasket against the wall to keep the epoxy in place until it cures.

Comment: We are far from sea and rivers here, so no boat stores around. But I like the gasket idea. I can measure the depth, put a gasket around it and use the gasket as a pressure holder for the bolt.

Comment: Just did the anchoring today. It was very hard to fill the whole hole with epoxy (it had a huge void inside the concrete) and the tape idea doesn't work very nicely because epoxy prevent everything from sticking to it, no matter how much I cleaned around the hole. In the end I wrapped tape around the bolt enough to "plug" the hole.